# How to store a parent with multiple children in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am looking for the proper way of storing a record with multiple children in Azure Table Storage, considering that:

1. It's not a SQL environment that I can define a one to many relationship between two tables
2. It's not a NoSQL DB like DocumentDB to conveniently store a JSON document with it's children which would be the ideal case for me.

The data schema is simple: a record that may have one or more children, something like this:

```
Parent
   |__ Child 1
   |__ Child 2
   |__ ...
```

The query requirements are simple and I am querying on Parent record fields for now. Something like: get parent records where Parent.IsLatest = true.

Couple of notes:

1. The reason I am choosing Azure Table Storage is affordability.
2. The affordable storage needs to be in Azure. Other environments won't work.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: @GauravMantri added to the question

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be a little bit complicated structure :). One more question, how are you going to query this data? Would you always be finding child items for a parent item? Or is it somewhat different? Please edit your question and include this detail.

Comment: @GauravMantri added to question :)

Comment: Thanks again :). I'm still confused :P. What's this `IsLatest` property? Is it defined at Child or Parent level? Can you please edit your question and describe your problem in detail. With Azure Tables, how you are going to query the data plays most important role in how you store the data. Unfortunately with the information you provided, I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: Adding to what @GauravMantri is asking about: if you're querying on a property that is neither the partition nor the row key, this will require either a partition scan (if you include partition id in the query), or an entire table scan, since properties other than partition key and row key are not indexed in any way (unlike, say, a document database that indexes any / all properties). So if you're querying a non-indexed property, when you talk about saving cost, at this point it's really cost of storage, not cost of queries (which could get quite expensive).

Comment: It may be worthwhile reading this guide from Storage team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide.

Comment: What I have in mind (not implemented yet) is to store parent in one table and children in another table. Records are immutable in both tables and partitioned by a common key. Once a parent and its children are updated, I remove current records and re-insert them with the partition key updated as {partitionkey-old} and then insert the updated parent and children with the same partition key {partitionkey}. This should be fast to query but there is a delete/reinsert involved since partition keys cannot be updated. Is this the right way?

Comment: You could use Partition as the parent ID and Row as the child ID. Assuming a single level of Parent-Child relationships, you could have parents only supplying a parent ID and children supplying both.